# How bad is my ssd disk?

Tags: ssd, hardware-failure, hard-drive-failure

Eventually I get very long boot times. Some times I have to re-install some programs because of segmentation fault. So I found my ssd disk, which is 12 months old, have some problems as seen in this picture:

[image]

How can I tell if it is about to break or if it has more time of life?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An increased reallocated sector count means that your SSD is starting to fail: There have been  errors while reading from, writing to or verifying `184` sectors.

`184` isn't *extremely* high. The threshold depends on each individual drive (consult your manual or a drive specific tool for this). But there's absolutely no way of telling if it will fail next year or within the next minute.

This is the wrong place for being cheap. If your SSD is only 12 month old, maybe it's still covered by the warranty. According to the model number of your SSD, you have an Intel 510 SSD. Contact Intel's customer service to find out if their [3-year limited warranty](http://www.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/CS-032509.htm) applies to your particular drive.

Even if you can't replace it without cost, you should get a new one; or be prepared to lose all your data.